# List with decimal numbers

Tags: html

is it possible to have `<li>` numbers like this?:

```
1.1 First Item
1.2 Second Item
2.1 Other item
```

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to do it is by using the CSS counter-increment property.
You could set sections and sub-sections as "Section 1", "1.1", "1.2", etc. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

```
<style>
    ol { counter-reset: item }
    li { display: block }
    li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
</style>

   <ol>
        <li>First level</li>
        <li>First level 2
            <ol>
                <li>Second level</li>
                <li>Second level 2
                    <ol><li>Third level</li></ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>           
    </ol>
```

Another great explanation:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-counter-increment/

Comment: This works great and is supported in basically all browsers at this point. Should be marked as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: This works but affects all lists on the page. Can anyone explain why when I wrap my `<ol>` in `<div class="nested-list">` so i can use a selector it then starts numbering in my case at 18? (there are other, closed, lists further up the page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS generated content and counters, however guess which browser doesn't support it...

If you need general support you'll need do it server-side or with JavaScript.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2009/05/css-content-counter-increment-counter-reset/

Answer (score 1):

This page lists all the available list style types in HTML (along with browser compatibility):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/lists.html

As you can see, sub-pointed numbers are not a supported option, so if you want to do it exactly as you've suggested, then you'll have to do it manually - either plain text or javascript or possible using CSS `before:` (this last option could have been my preferred choice, except that it won't work in older versions of IE)

Alternatively, just accept that HTML doesn't support it, and go with an alternative numbering scheme that is supported. Using nested lists will allow you to have the outer list numbered 1,2,3, etc while the inner list is numbered I, II, III, IV, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this little [jQuery snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/M9zq9/)

```
$("ol").each(function(i) {
    $(this).children("li").not(":has(ol)").each(function(n, el) {
       $(this).prepend("<span>" + i + "." + (n+1) + " </span>");
    });
});
```

produces the desired effect, but only works with 2 levels given this type of layout:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol
```